# get value of range input using javascript after user stop dragging

Tags: javascript, laravel, api

I am trying to create filter for products based on price

[image]

The value will be sent to server using ajax so i need the last value

```
document.querySelector('#price-slider').onchange = e=>console.log(e.target.value)
```

I use this line of code to get the value but the problem is this is firing as long as the user is dragging

```
<div class="range-slider">
    <input id="price-slider" type="text" class="js-range-slider" value="" />
</div>
```

I've tried ondragend but it doesn't work

any idea how i can get the last value or another way to send this data for the backend without hitting it while user is dragging the range indicator ?

Comment: That sounds to me like a massive failure in the library you're using. `oninput` should fire every tick of dragging, whereas `onchange` should only fire once when the dragging stops...

Comment: I believe it should be working like that but idk why I am getting this weird behavior

Comment: The code is using ionRangeSlider idk if this is going to help :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to doc of ionRangeSlider
http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/api.html use onFinish instead of onchange.

Comment: I just found that out i was trying to find a way to use it outside the init if you can help with that !